# How do I use forecast package but not refering to the entire data?

Tags: r, arima, forecast

I am doing a project where I try to evaluate how well different ARIMA models estimate the stock price. I have a data of stock prices throughout the entire year. Let's say I would like to predict the price on the 101th day using data from the first 100 days in (0,1,0) ARIMA model. How do I do it? I only know how to refer to the entire dataset

```
fit <- auto.arima(data)
prediction <- forecast(fit,h=20)
```

That gives me estimates for the next 20 days using the data from the entire year. My aim is to compare the estimations with actual data.

Comment: Are you looking for `fitted(fit)`? This is the same as `data - resid(fit)`, as it should be. `identical(fitted(fit), data - resid(fit))` returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look here: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/rolling-forecasts/

```
library(fpp)
h <- 5
train <- window(hsales,end=1989.99)
test <- window(hsales,start=1990)
n <- length(test) - h + 1
fit <- auto.arima(train)
order <- arimaorder(fit)
fcmat <- matrix(0, nrow=n, ncol=h)
for(i in 1:n) {  
  x <- window(hsales, end=1989.99 + (i-1)/12)
  refit <- Arima(x, order=order[1:3], seasonal=order[4:6])
  fcmat[i,] <- forecast(refit, h=h)$mean
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a plain forecast from the first 100 values, you could try subsetting your data first and then fit the model. If you want the forecast function to only predict the next value, you need to set the forecast horizon to `h = 1`

```
# Only select the first 100 obs from your dataset
subset <- data[1:100]
fit <- auto.arima(subset)
prediction <- forecast(fit, h=1)
```

EDIT: If you want to compare the data afterwards you can extract the 101th index and compare it using the `accuracy` function from the `forecast` package

```r
library(forecast)
# Extract the 101th index
test_value <- data[101]
accuracy(prediction, test_value)
```

See also `?accuracy` for help